# How to manipulate the knee of the curve of an exponential function?

Tags: exponential-function

I want to be able to manipulate the point of inflection of an exponential curve equation:$$a\exp\{xb\}.$$
could somebody  tell me which parameter I may introduce in such a formula in order to make the resultant curve more bent, without changing anything else?

This pic represents what I want to do with the curve
[image]

Comment: Desmos is nice for playing with coefficients: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jrbmek3mae

Comment: The "knee" you wan to move would not be called a "point of inflection" by mathematicians. They use that term to refer to a place where curvature changes sign.

Comment: Excel lets you play with parameters in curve fitting. Look at the "Trend Line" function.

Comment: I already tried in excell and could not do what I want. By using desmos, it looks like what I want to do is not possible with an exponential function, but I should use another function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply your exponential with a second degree polynomial, $x^2$: 
$$f(x)=x^2ae^{bx+c}$$

You can then fiddle with $c$ to slide the whole graph left again. For example, open this [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jrbmek3mae)-link in two different tabs and leave one of them as is. Then multiply the function in the other by $x^2$ and change $c$ to around $-5.7$. Now change between the two tabs to see the change.